# Openshift Route - Cookie specification - Istio Routing

Tags: virtualization, routing, route, istio, openshift

I have requirement to pass cookie or headers in openshift route to istio virtual service and decide the traffic routing based on cookie or header passed from route to virtualservice.
Please share pointers on the same.

Comment: Did you check https://www.itwonderlab.com/en/istio-patterns-traffic-splitting-in-kubernetes-header-based/#elementor-toc__heading-anchor-3

Comment: I have checked this article. this article has the info provided on how to match cookie and header in virtual service and route request accordingly.
But i am looking on, how to attach this cookie or header in openshift route which i am using to route the traffic into istio ingressgateway service ->istio-gateway->istio-virtualservice